# using a function to turn a list of strings separated by commas into integers

Tags: python, list

"The point of this code is to input a list of integers as strings and have the output be a list of integers, thus allowing the user to find the average. I can't seem to understand why it is not working, I keep getting splitting issues"

```
def is_integer(s):

    if s == s.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False


def are_all_integers(strs):

    for s in strs.split(","):
        if s == s.isdigit:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def strs_to_num(strs):

    integers = []
    for s in strs:
        integers.append(int(s))
    return integers


def get_ints():

    list_of_integers = []
    s = input("Enter some digits: ")
    s = s.split()
    while (len(s) < 2) and (are_all_integers(s) is False):
        s = input("invalid input, try again: ")
    for integer in s:
        strs_to_num(integer)
        list_of_integers.append(integer)

    return list_of_integers


def main():

    s = get_ints()
    avg = sum(s)/len(s)
    print(sum(s))
    print(len(s))
    print("The average of these numbers are", avg)


main()
```

Comment: For starters, change `strs.split(",")` to `strs` - it's _already_ a list, you don't have to split it a 2nd time. That's just one of the bugs in your code though. Honestly, I think there are too many bugs in this code for it to be suitable for StackOverflow. It would be unreasonable to expect anyone to fix all of that for you.

Comment: Sorry about that, pretty new to the site and coding so I am not too familiar with the format or how things would look when properly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1) 
If you use descriptive variable names you will find 
that the code is easier to read.

You use the name **s** for:

- input string - "4 5 6"
- list of strings - ["4","5","6"]
- string repr. of int - "4"
- list of integers - [4,5,6]

This gets confusing.

2)
You never call the function `is_integer(s)` so you 
can delete it.

3)
The function `are_all_integers()` tries to split the 
list of integer strings. Then it checks if s is equal 
to s.isdigit. As s is True (!= '') and s.isdigit (which 
has the value "`<built-in method isdigit of str object at 0x0547B320>`") 
is also True, the whole expression is True.

The correct expression would be: if `s.isdigit()`. You 
have to have parenthesis at the end or Python will not 
know that you are asking for the **value** of the function.

Also, the function `are_all_integers()` returns True for the first item that 
is an integer and will not evaluate subsequent strings in the list.

4)
The while loop condition should be OR:ed. Then you must split 
the input string to create the list passed to `are_all_integers()`.

5)
The function `strs_to_num()` can be replaced by builtin function `int()`.

6) 
Spend some time learning how to debug your code. At your level this 
can be accomplished by working in small steps and printing intermediate 
results to the console. Google for help on this and don't bother with 
logging or debugging tools just yet.